# Function template overloads resolution confusion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, c++17

I'm wondering how calls to these two overloads of `std::make_optional` are resolved:

```
template< class T >
constexpr std::optional<std::decay_t<T>> make_optional( T&& value );

template< class T, class... Args >
constexpr std::optional<T> make_optional( Args&&... args );
```

I know invocation without explicit template argument like `make_optional(123)` will call the first one, but how about `make_optional<int>(123)`? Which overload will be selected, and by what rules?

**UPDATE:** And if I write say `make_optional<string>("hello world")`, I will be invoking the second overload (even though the string literal can be implicitly converted to a `string`), correct?

Comment: where library (and namespace) declare them? [`std::experimental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/optional) seems to define the first one only.

Comment: @Nawaz: The second overload of `make_optional` comes from [P0032 (PDF)](http://wg21.link/P0032), which was [forwarded to LWG before Oulu](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100), apparently. Though P0091 may make it obsolete, so they may not have adopted it. So at present, Nawaz is correct: the second overload does not exist.

Comment: @NicolBolas [It exists](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/1882aa320a101fcfdb7a6d4de40197982209ce30).

Comment: @Nawaz I saw them at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload resolution starts with determining the viable candidates, choosing the one with the best conversion sequence, and then going through the list of tiebreakers.

---

`make_optional(123)` has only one viable candidate, since `T` is a non-deduced context in the second overload. Thus, it's trivially the best viable candidate.

---

`make_optional<int>(123)` gives us two viable candidates:

- `make_optional(int&& )` with `[T=int]`
- `make_optional<int>(int&& )` with `[T=int, Args={int}]`

The function take identical arguments (`int&&`), so they're trivially equally viable with identical conversion sequences. The first overload is a more specialized function template than the second overload (since it takes a single argument instead of a variadic pack), so it's the one preferred.

---

`make_optional<string>("hello world")` gives us two viable candidates:

- `make_optional(string&& )` with `[T=string]`
- `make_optional<string>(const char(&)[12] )` with `[T=string, Args={const char (&)[12]}]`

Here, the two functions don't take the same argument - the first takes a `string&&` (which would require a user-defined conversion from the string literal) and the second takes a `const char(&)[12]` (which is an Exact Match). Hence, the second overload has the better conversion sequence and is preferred.